# How to package and run a Flask app as a Windows .exe file and share with colleagues across local network?

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, exe

I currently built a Flask app for my company, and I would like to package it as an .exe file for my colleagues to use within same network. How do I go about this?

I have tried using webview and then pyinstaller but that doesn't seem to work as I expect. The home page route '/' works after running the .exe file but once I try to click on another route, it says "Hmm... this page is unfortunately not accessible.". In addition to templates file, I have static files that includes CSS and uploaded images folder.

I tried to get a view that looks like a normal application and then run a pyinstaller to get an .exe file. I expect it to work normally as it would if it runs on the browser. Also, I would like to the host and port to be accessible to my colleagues.

Comment: How did you package the Flask app, and how is it run as an exe file? What does "click" mean in "*once I try to click on another route"*? Because the error "*Hmm... this page is unfortunately not accessible.*" does not look like a Flask error, so I'm guessing from some other part of your app. In that case, you'll need to provide an [mcve] of the app and how you package it as an exe.